# Numerical Integration on Some Points in xy-plane

Tags: numerical-methods, approximate-integration

I have an assignment to finding the result of the integration of some points given in the closed interval $[0,1.2]$ with the method of Trapezoidal Rule, Simpson 1/3 and Simpson 3/8 rule. The problem on the given points is the step size is not uniform. The given points are :

| $x$ | $f(x)$ |
| --- | --- |
| $0$ | $1$ |
| $0.2$ | $1.491824698$ |
| $0.4$ | $2.225540928$ |
| $0.5$ | $2.718281828$ |
| $0.6$ | $3.320116923$ |
| $0.7$ | $4.055199967$ |
| $1$ | $7.389056099$ |
| $1.1$ | $9.025013499$ |
| $1.2$ | $11.02317638$ |

Firstly my approach is to use Trapezoidal rule in the sub-interval with the same step size, which is $[0,0.4];[0.4,0.7];[1,1.2]$. And then I sum up all the value and get $3.361908926$. Is this the right approach? How about the Simpson method? I cant use the 1/3 rule because the amount of data in the given sub-interval is not even, that's also the problem with 3/8rule. How do I proceed?

Comment: What about the $[0.7 , 1]$ region?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you mention are based in interpolation, i.e. you compute the integral of an interpolating polynomial. Even though the formulas for those quadrature rules are presented for equally spaced points, you can always compute the adequate interpolating polynomials and respective integrals.

In the case of the trapezoidal method, it is even simpler: the composite trapezoidal method corresponds to the application of the simple method to each sub-interval and so, if you have $a=x_0< x_1 < \cdots < x_n=b$, then
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} f(x) dx=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{x_{i+1}-x_i}{2}\cdot (f(x_i)+f(x_{i+1})) = 5.07855
$$

For Simpson, you can use the usual formula in the intervals with
$$
x = 0, 0.2, 0.4; \quad x = 0.4, 0.5, 0.6; \quad x=1, 1.1, 1.2
$$

And then add an estimate for the integral in $[0.6, 1]$, given by
$$
\int_{0.6}^1f(x) dx \approx \int_{0.6}^1 p_2(x) dx = \int_{0.6}^1 9.40506 x^2-4.87575 x+2.85974 dx =2.04151$$

Comment: Sorry sir, how did you came up for the estimation in $[0.6,1]$(the polynomial integrand) ? Also for the simpson do you mean i sum up all integral i use in the subinterval + the estimation?

Comment: can I use Simpson 3/8 too here? Cause it seems it doesnt fit with Simpson3/8 rule.

Comment: @AjiWibowo from the function values at $x = 0.6, 0.7, 1$ you compute the interpolating polynomial $p_2(x)$ (lookup Lagrange interpolating polynomial or Newton's divided differences). Simpson's rule just corresponds to approximate the integrakl of $f$ by the integral of $p_2$. For the estimate on the whole interval, you just need to add the four terms (three standard and this last one).

Comment: Simpson's 3/8 rule comes from replacing $f$ by a polynomial of order 3. You cannot apply it with this exact number of points. You have two possibilities: either applying a different rule in one of the sub-intervals or keep only 10 points in order to be able to apply the composed Simpson 3/8 rule with 3 sub-intervals.

Comment: I use $[0.4,0.7]$ interval for simpson 3/8 rule and the other one $[0,0.4]$ and $[0.7,1.2]$ I use Lagrange interpolation and integrate it. The result is much more great rather than the simpson 1/3. Also, I tried to graph the data and assuming the function that interpolate the data is $e^{2x}$ so i use that to see the error for those 3 method.
Thank you so much sir!